# Could not validate beacon script on not home page of external site

Tags: fxm

I have external site with home page url - externalsitedomain.com/mainpage and I would like to use FXM for it. I put beacon script in the head tag of externalsitedomain.com/mainpage, but I see an error in FXM editor:

> Could not validate beacon script - The remote server returned an
>   error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Is it possible to connect this external site to FXM if it is available on externalsitedomain.com/mainpage page only and externalsitedomain.com returns 503 (Service Unavailable) error?

sitecore 9.3

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue in sitecore 9.3. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @indumathi in my case I had bad html to render in EE. I caught this content after GetExternalPageContentProcessor pipeline to fix it and return well-formed html for the rendering external page.